# How to allocate and free aligned memory in C

Tags: c, alignment, memory-mapped-files, memory-alignment

How do you allocate memory that's aligned to a specific boundary in C (e.g., cache line boundary)?  I'm looking for malloc/free like implementation that ideally would be as portable as possible --- at least between 32 and 64 bit architectures.

Edit to add: In other words, I'm looking for something that would behave like (the now obsolete?) [memalign](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/memalign.3.asp) function, which can be freed using free.

Comment: Have you checked these two answers on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me/227900#227900 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855896/memory-alignment-on-modern-processors?

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I would like something that functions more like malloc, returns one value that is the aligned pointer, then have another function similar to free, that's called on that pointer. Applying a solution such as the ones you pointed requires either passing around two values, or recalculating the alignment whenever it's needed.  I'm looking for something similar to memalign.  Thanks for pointing those answers out though.

Comment: There's `posix_memalign()` on appropriate machines - has a different interface from `memalign()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aligned malloc() in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839922/aligned-malloc-in-gcc)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a solution, which encapsulates the call to malloc, allocates a bigger buffer for alignment purpose, and stores the original allocated address just before the aligned buffer for a later call to free.

```
// cache line
#define ALIGN 64

void *aligned_malloc(int size) {
    void *mem = malloc(size+ALIGN+sizeof(void*));
    void **ptr = (void**)((uintptr_t)(mem+ALIGN+sizeof(void*)) & ~(ALIGN-1));
    ptr[-1] = mem;
    return ptr;
}

void aligned_free(void *ptr) {
    free(((void**)ptr)[-1]);
}
```

Comment: with the new standards, you should consider replacing the cast to `long` with a cast to `uintptr_t`

Comment: @Jermoe In particular, the code does not work on 64-bit Windows

Comment: @Jerome — Any particular reason you say `malloc(size+ALIGN+sizeof(void*))` and not `malloc(size+ALIGN-1+sizeof(void*))`? If you're aligning to an *n*-byte boundary, then you only ever need at most *n* – 1 extra bytes.

Comment: This code is somewhat confusing in its use of the void** in the return statement.

Comment: Is it okay to add +ALIGN-1 instead of +ALIGN?

void *aligned_malloc(int size) {
    void *mem = malloc(size+ALIGN-1+sizeof(void*));
    void **ptr = (void**)((long)(mem+ALIGN-1+sizeof(void*)) & ~(ALIGN-1));
    ptr[-1] = mem;
    return ptr;
}

Comment: so when you free you get a cache miss

Comment: How is this different from free(ptr)?

Answer (score 15):

Use `posix_memalign`/`free`.

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size); 

void* ptr;
int rc = posix_memalign(&ptr, alignment, size);
...
free(ptr)
```

`posix_memalign` is a standard replacement for `memalign` which, as you mention is obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

What compiler are you using?  If you're on MSVC, you can try [`_aligned_malloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28VS.80%29.aspx) and `_aligned_free()`.

Comment: Sun's compiler for Solaris/SPARC and gcc for Linux/x86

Comment: Looks like Sun supports memalign(): http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5168/malloc-3c?a=view

I don't see any indication that memalign() is deprecated in the current glibc: http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/libc/malloc/malloc.h?revision=1.32&root=libc&view=markup

Comment: Links that work: [_aligned_free](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-free?view=msvc-170), [_aligned_malloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=msvc-170).