# aligned malloc() in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, memory-alignment

Is there any standardized function in GCC or glibc to allocate memory block at aligned pointer?
Like [_align_malloc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2019) in MSVC?

Comment: stdlib only version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/how-to-allocate-aligned-memory-only-using-the-standard-library

Answer (score 40):

Since the question was asked, a new function was standardized by C11:

```
void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

and it is available in glibc (not on windows as far as I know). It takes its arguments in the same order as `memalign`, the reverse of Microsoft's `_aligned_malloc`, and uses the same `free` function as usual for deallocation.

A subtle difference is that `aligned_alloc` requires `size` to be a multiple of `alignment`.

Answer (score 18):

> The [`posix_memalign()`][1] function provides aligned memory allocation and
>   has been available since glibc 2.1.91.

But not necessarily with other compilers: quoting the standard
"The posix_memalign() function is part of the Advisory Information option and need not be provided on all implementations."

Answer (score 11):

There are `_mm_malloc` and `_mm_free` which are supported by most compilers of the x86/x64 world, with at least:

- gcc
- MinGW (gcc win32/win64)
- MSVC
- clang
- ICC

AFAIK, these functions are not a standard at all. But it is to my knowledge the most supported ones. Other functions are more compiler specific:

- _aligned_malloc is MSVC and MinGW only
- posix memalign functions are not supported by at least MSVC

There are also C11 standard functions but unfortunately they are not in c++11, and including them in c++ require non standard preprocessor defines...

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what kind of alignment you expect. Do you want a stricter alignment, or a more relaxed alignment?

`malloc` by definition is guaranteed to return a pointer that is properly aligned for storing any standard type in C program (and, therefore, any type built from standard types). Is it what your are looking for? Or do you need something different?

Comment: A common problem is that SIMD types (like SSE vectors) aren't considered "standard types", and so they have stricter alignment requirements than `malloc` provides.

Comment: Another reason for wanting to do this is performance. By aligning a data structure so it spans `n` instead of `n+1` L1 cache lines which are typically 4096 bytes or so in size, you get faster memory access on average. For certain applications, say audio processing, where buffers are the size of an L1 cache line, or a small multiple of that size, this can make a big difference.

Comment: @nitro2k01: Cache lines are much smaller e.g. 32 on x86 and 64 on amd64. Pages OTOH are 4k.

Answer (score 1):

Since C11 (and C++17) there is standard library function [`aligned_alloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) with signature:

```
void *aligned_alloc( size_t alignment, size_t size );
```

You must `#include <stdlib.h>` to use it. The `size` parameter must be a multiple of `alignment`. On failure returns null pointer. Allocated pointer is freed using [`std::free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free).

Although not all compilers may have implemented this standard function. For example MSVC didn't implement it for next reason (read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/cstdlib?view=msvc-160)):

> MSVC doesn't support the aligned_alloc function. C11 specified aligned_alloc() in a way that's incompatible with the Microsoft implementation of free(), namely, that free() must be able to handle highly aligned allocations.

For MSVC [`_aligned_malloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=msvc-160) and [`_aligned_free()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-free?view=msvc-160) must be used.

But GCC/G++ has this standard `aligned_alloc()`, at least I tested this on Windows+Cygwin.

Comment: The question wasn't about C++. Also, in general, if the question to some stack overflow question has already been satisfactorily answered, another submission, obfuscates unless providing a significant addition, revision, or argument.

Comment: Microsoft's "reasoning" for not implementing `aligned_alloc()` is a joke.  [Per the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.1p2): "The `aligned_alloc` function allocates space for an object whose alignment is specified by `alignment`, whose size is specified by `size`, and whose value is indeterminate. The value of alignment shall be a valid alignment supported by the implementation and the value of `size` shall be an integral multiple of `alignment`."  Any half-decent undergrad can implement that.