# Align the start of an array in dynamic memory in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-alignment, calloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aligned memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061392/aligned-memory-management)

I have an array which I am declaring like this

```
int * myarray;
int num_of_element;

myarry = (int*) calloc(num_of_elements, sizeof(int));
```

The size of an int is 4 bytes however I want to ensure that my array starts on an 8 byte boundary - so I can efficiently load two values each time. Is there a different way or something else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways.

2. Over-allocate, and round up the returned address to the desired alignment.
3. Define a union with a type whose alignment is the desired one, generally `double`. This requires low-level knowledge but is not optimal when you want to allocate an array.

[Also, you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Doesn't calloc already ensure the pointer returned is aligned with every possible type, including that double?

Comment: Yes, at least on BSD and Linux. @PiotrKalinowski

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried `posix_memalign` ?

> The  function  posix_memalign()  allocates `size` bytes and places the address of the allocated memory in `*memptr`.  The address of the allocated memory will be a multiple of `alignment`, which must be a
>          power of two and a multiple of `sizeof(void *)`.

Example:

```
if (posix_memalign(&myarray, 8, num_of_elements*sizeof(int)) != 0) {
    // failed
}
```

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/posix_memalign.html

Linux posix_memalign manpage also documents aligned_alloc() (c11), memalign() (obsolete) :

https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html