# Which guarantees does malloc make about memory alignment?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I came across the following code:

```
int main()
{
    char *A=(char *)malloc(20);
    char *B=(char *)malloc(10);
    char *C=(char *)malloc(10);
    printf("\n%d",A);
    printf("\t%d",B);
    printf("\t%d\n",C);
    return 0;
}  
//output--   152928264     152928288    152928304
```

I want to know how the allocation and padding is done by `malloc()`. Looking at the output I can see that the starting address is a multiple of 8. Arethere any other rules?

Comment: Whatever "rules" you "learn" by studying what malloc does on your computer ... should be unlearned as soon as you move to another computer, or change compiler options, or the phase of the moon changes, ..., ... :)

Comment: To print a pointer you really should use `"%p"` and cast to `void*`: `printf("%p", (void*)A);`

Comment: i dont really understand your question.

Comment: i want to know standard rules malloc follows while allocating memory.Platform - Linux 32 Bit,gcc Compiler

Comment: @Amol Sharma: there are *no* "standard rules" for this

Comment: why do you want to know?

Comment: i agree i should have used %p for printing pointers but that doesn't affect the question or answer

Comment: @PaulR you want to say that the output will depend on the machine..that is, starting address need not to be a multiple of 8.

Comment: @Amol: the only assumption you can make about returned malloc addresses is the minimum alignment for a given platform

Comment: @PaulR ok thanx...i just wanted to confirm that only

Comment: how to force align: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839922/aligned-malloc-in-gcc

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Accdording to [this documentation page](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_31.html),

> the address of a block returned by malloc or realloc in the GNU system is always a multiple of eight (or sixteen on 64-bit systems).

In general, `malloc` implementations are system-specific. All of them keep some memory for their own bookkeeping (e.g. the actual length of the allocated block) in order to be able to release that memory correctly when you call `free`. If you need to align to a specific boundary, use other functions, such as [`posix_memalign`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign).

Answer (score 9):

The C standard says that the result of `malloc()` must be cast-able to any legit pointer type. So

`... = (DataType *)malloc(...);`

must be possible, regardless what type `DataType` is.

If a system has memory alignment requirements for certain data types, `malloc()` has to take that into account. And since `malloc()` cannot know to which pointer type you are going to cast the result, it always must follow the strictest memory alignment requirement.

The original wording in the standard is:

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

Source: *ISO/IEC 9899:201x* (aka *ISO C11*)

E.g. if a system requires `int` to be 4 byte aligned and `long` to be 8 byte aligned, `malloc()` must return memory that is 8 byte aligned because it cannot know if you are going to cast the result to to `int *` or to `long *`.

Theoretically, if you request less than `sizeof(long)` bytes, a cast to `long *` is invalid as a `long` would not even fit into that memory. One might think that in that case `malloc()` could choose a smaller alignment but that's not what the standard says. The alignment requirement in the standard does not depend on the size of the allocation!

Since many CPUs as well as many operation system do have alignment requirements, most malloc implementation will always return aligned memory but which alignment rules it follows is system specific. There are also CPUs and systems that have no alignment requirements in which case `malloc()` may as well return unaligned memory.

If you depend on a specific alignment, you can either use `aligned_alloc()`, which is defined in the *ISO C11* standard and thus portable to all systems for that a C11 compiler exists or you can use `posix_memalign()`, which is defined in IEEE Std *1003.1-2001* (aka *POSIX 2001*) and is available on all POSIX conforming systems as well as systems that try to be as POSIX conforming as possible (Linux for example).

Fun fact:
`malloc()` on macOS always returns memory that is 16 byte aligned, despite the fact that no data type on macOS has a memory alignment requirement beyond 8. The reason for that is SSE. Some SSE instructions have a 16 byte alignment requirement and by ensuring that `malloc()` always returns memory that is 16 byte aligned, Apple can very often use SSE optimization in its standard library.

Answer (score 7):

The only standard rule is that the address returned by `malloc` will be suitably aligned to store any kind of variable. What exactly that means is platform-specific (since alignment requirements vary from platform to platform).

Answer (score 0):

For 32 bit Linux system:
When malloc() allocate memory, it allocate memory in multiple of 8 (padding of 8) and allocate extra 8 byte for bookkeeping. 
For example:

> malloc(10) and malloc (12) will allocate 24 Bytes memory (16 Bytes after padding + 8
>   Byte for bookkeeping).

malloc() do padding because the addresses returned will be multiples of eight, and thus will be valid for pointers of any type. Bookkeeping 8 bytes is used when we call free function. Bookkeeping bytes stores length of allocated memory.