# Why does assignment to an element of an AVX-Vector-wrapper-class-object-array provoke access violation errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, access-violation, avx

I am trying to do some vector stuff and wrote a wrapper for the m256d datatype from immintrin.h to use overloaded operators.
The following example should give you a basic idea.

#### Class definition

```
#include <immintrin.h>
using namespace std;
class vwrap {
public:
  __m256d d;
  vwrap(void) { 
    this->d = _mm256_set_pd(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0); 
  }
  void init (const double &a, const double &b, const double &c) { 
    this->d = _mm256_set_pd(0.0,c,b,a);
  }
};
```

#### Array of vwrap objects

Let's imagine an array of vwrap that is allocated dynamically:

```
vwrap *a = (vwrap*) malloc(sizeof(vwrap)*2);
```

#### Access violation errors

Using a function of a vwrap object that contains a mm256-set-function... provokes an access violation error.

```
a[0].init(1.3,2.3,1.2);
```

The same thing is happening for assigning d with a mm256-set-function 
(assigning another m256d-object doesn't work as well):

```
a[0].d = _mm256_set_pd(1,2,3,4);
```

Copying data from another object isn't working, too.

```
vwrap b;
a[0].d = b.d;
```

#### Stuff that works

The m256d-object can be manipulated without any problems:

```
a[0].d.m256d_f64[0] = 1.0;
a[0].d.m256d_f64[1] = 2.0;
a[0].d.m256d_f64[2] = 3.0;
a[0].d.m256d_f64[3] = 4.0;
```

The assignments are working in case of a normal class instance:

```
vwrap b,c;
__mm256d t = _mm256_set_pd(1,2,3,5);
b.d = _mm256_set_pd(1,2,3,4); 
b.d = t;
b.d = c.d;
```

I don't get the problem.
Why can't I use the _mm256 functions (or assign a m256d-object) in case of a class array?
My only idea is to avoid using the mm256-functions and manipulate the double values directly.
But this is not what I intentionally wanted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely an [alignment problem](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_details.htm). `__m256d` need to be aligned on 32 byte boundaries. You shouldn't use `malloc` when alignment is a concern, use [`new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free) or [aligned `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839922/aligned-malloc-in-gcc).

The your stack-allocated variables work correctly is that the compiler aligns them properly, because it knows they need to be aligned. Whereas when you call `malloc`, there's no way the runtime knows what you plan to store in the memory it gives you. Therefore, you need to either  explicitly request alignment using aligned `malloc`, or use type-aware allocation which is what `new` is for.

Changing

```
vwrap *a = (vwrap*) malloc(sizeof(vwrap)*2);
```

to

```
vwrap *a = new vwrap[2];
```

```
vwrap *a = (vwrap*) _aligned_malloc(sizeof(vwrap)*2, 32);
```

should work.

**EDIT**: After trying this out on Windows with GCC 4.6.1 (compiler switch `-march=corei7-avx`) it seems `new` doesn't respect alignment requirements. Changing the new call to use `_aligned_malloc` works.

Comment: Thank you! In fact the new vwrap[2] does not work but it was in fact a matter of alignment. 

`vwrap *a = (vwrap*) _aligned_malloc(sizeof(vwrap)*2, 32);` made is work.