# should std::vector honour alignof(value_type)?

Tags: c++, c++11, alignment, containers

If I define a simple type with a certain alignment requirement, shouldn't a `std::vector<t>` of said type honour the alignment *for every single element*?

Consider the following example

```
typedef std::array<double,3> alignas(32) avx_point;
std::vector<avx_point> x(10);
assert(!(std::ptrdiff_t(&(x[0]))&31) &&   // assert that x[0] is 32-byte aligned
       !(std::ptrdiff_t(&(x[1]))&31));    // assert that x[1] is 32-byte aligned
```

I found that the alignment requirement is silently (without any warning) violated by clang 3.2 (with or without `-stdlib=libc++`), while gcc 4.8.0 issues a warning that it ignores the attributes on the template argument to `std::vector` (the intel compiler is too daft to understand `alignas`, but if I use `__declspec(align(32))` instead, it behaves like clang). Both create code that triggers the assert.

So, is this correct behaviour or a bug of clang (and icpc) and an issue with gcc?

**edit**
to answer a question raised in the comments: if I define

```
typedef typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof (avx_point),
                                      alignof(avx_point)>::type avx_storage;
```

I get

```
sizeof (avx_storage) == 32;
alignof(avx_storage) == 32;
```

but `std::vector<avx_storage>` still fails to align the first element (and hence all the others too) for clang and gcc (without warning this time). So there are apparently two issues with the implementations: first, that `std::allocator<type>` ignores any alignment requirements even for the first element (illegal?) and second, that no padding is applied to ensure alignment of subsequent elements.

––––––––––––

**edit**  There is a [related, more practical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456236/how-is-a-vectors-data-aligned) for how to obtain memory suitably aligned for SSE/AVX operations. In contrast, I want to know whether `std::vector<>` (or `std::allocator<>`) shouldn't honour `alignas` as of the C++ standard (as of 2011). None of the answers to that other question are suitable answers to this one.

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you compare `std::vector<std::aligned_storage<sizeof(avx_point), 32>>` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is a vector's data aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456236/how-is-a-vectors-data-aligned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> first, that std::allocator ignores any alignment requirements even for the first element (illegal?)

I'm far from being an expert on allocators but it seems to me that, unfortunately, this is legal behaviour. More precisely, an allocator might ignore the requested alignment. Indeed, [allocator.requirements], 17.6.3.5/6 states:

> If the alignment associated with a specific over-aligned type is not supported by an allocator, instantiation
>   of the allocator for that type may fail. **The allocator also may silently ignore the requested alignment**.

You can write your own allocator to give you aligned memory. I've done that before at my work but, unfortunately, for copyright reasons, I cannot disclose the code :-( All I can say, is the obvious thing: it was based on `_aligned_malloc` and `_aligned_free` (which are Microsoft extensions). Or you can Google for "aligned allocator" and a few options will come up, one of which is

https://gist.github.com/donny-dont/1471329

I emphasize that I'm not the author of this aligned allocator and I've never used it.

**Update**

The aligned allocator above is for Visual Studio/Windows but it can be used as a base for implementing aligned allocators on other platforms. You can use the posix [`memalign`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) family of functions or the C11 function `aligned_alloc`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839922/aligned-malloc-in-gcc) post.

Comment: What is the logic of the standard to introduce the keywords `alignas` and `alignof` only for it to allow allocators to ignore them? btw, I have my own `aligned_allocator<>`, which works very well (and does not have any stupid copyright issues).

Comment: Boost provides an aligned allocator as well: `boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<Type, Alignment>`.