# corrupted size vs. prev_size in C

Tags: c, pthreads, dynamic-memory-allocation

I get "corrupted size vs prev_size" error whenever I allocate a dynamic memory in a thread. Whenever I allocate the memory in main() it works fine. But allocating dynamic memory in thread produces the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *fib(void *p);
struct mystruct
{
    int *array;
    int size;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    struct mystruct obj;

    obj.size = atoi(argv[1]);;

    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, fib, (void *)&obj);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}

void *fib (void *p)
{
    struct mystruct *x = (struct mystruct *)p;
    x->array = (int *) malloc (x->size);

    for (int i=0; i<x->size; i++){
        x->array[i] = i;
        printf("The array is = %d\n", x->array[i]);
    }   
}
```

I've added snapshot for details.

[image: error saying corrupted size vs prev_size]

Thanks!

Comment: The size passed to [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) is the size *in bytes*. Not the number of "elements" (which is impossible since `malloc` doesn't know what you're actually allocating memory for).

Comment: `(int *) malloc (x->size)` --> `malloc (sizeof *(x->array) * x->size)`

Comment: For future questions please do not add screenshots of plain text. You can simply copy&paste that text into your question.

Comment: before accessing beyond `argv[0]`, always check `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user.

Answer (score 5):

Try with the following line:

```
x->array =  malloc (x->size*sizeof(int));
```

You need to allocate space for `x->size` integers. `malloc` accepts as parameter the number of bytes you need. And for `n` `int` you need `n` times the size in bytes of a single `int`.

Do not forget to `return` from the main.

Comment: in C, the heap memory allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` have a return type of `void*`  which can be assigned to an pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: "Do not forget to return from the main. " I take it you actually mean "do not forget to return the thread status to main"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved by using an "aligned" version of *malloc*, i.e.: allocated memory will be aligned. I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1920516/2155258.

Comment: The issue in OP's code is not really about alignment, it's about requesting an incorrectly *sized* memory block. Not also that the `malloc` does some alignment: *If allocation succeeds, returns a pointer that is suitably aligned for any object type with fundamental alignment.*