# How come printf is printing a non-null terminated string?

Tags: c

The C programming book says that my string must be null terminated to print it using [printf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string), but still the following program prints the string despite it being non-null terminated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char str[10];
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        str[i] = (char)(i+97);
    }

    printf("%s", str);
}
```

I am using the [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) IDE.

Comment: You just happened to get lucky, there was a `0` somewhere right after that array. You've just exploited something seasoned programmers call "undefined behavior". Don't count on being able to do that everywhere, most programs would crash.

Comment: I have run the loop 1000 times but it always runs the same without any issues . Should I consider changing my compiler from codeblocks ? thanks .

Comment: undefined doesn't mean non-repeatable. Try compiling with different flags, or compiling on a different architecture.

Comment: This is just like drunk driving. If you do that, you will get away most of the times. You are just endangering yourself and others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767284/using-printf-with-a-non-null-terminated-string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's *undefined behavior* to read beyond the bounds of an array. You were actually *unlucky* it didn't crash. If you run it enough times or call it in a function, it may (or may not) crash.

You should always terminate the string, or use a width specifier:

```
printf("%.10s", str);
```

Comment: I think I have a new doubt , if I do not terminate a string with a null character and use the width specifier then will it never crash ?

Comment: @NikunjBanka no it won't, as long as you don't exceed the array bounds you're okay.

Answer (score 5):

Whatever is after the 10th element of `str` happens to be a null. That null is outside the defined bounds of the array, but C doesn't have array bounds checking.  It's just luck in your case that that's how it worked out.

Comment: thanks but now I have run the same code in a loop 1000 times and each time it works without any issues . So now shall I consider this a matter of concern with the compiler itself ?(that it is automatically placing a null character )

Comment: Any time you find yourself wondering if the compiler is broken, you aren't looking hard enough at your own code or your own understanding of the problem.  As a novice, *always* assume that the problem is with you.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int i ;

    for(i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++ ) {

        char str[10] ;

        for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {

            str[i] = (char)(i+97) ;

        }



        printf("%s",str) ;

    }

    return 0 ;
}

Comment: @user189535:  So now declare another array on the next line after `char str[10]`.  Call it `char str2[10]`.  Fill it with 'B' or whatever you want.  Now print str and see what happens.

Comment: yeah that caught the problem ! Now it is printing a garbage value too! how did you figure that out ?

Comment: @NikunjBanka:  Well, technically it was luck that it printed garbage.  I meant to say to declare an array on the line *before* str[10].  Depends on your machine architecture.  But anyway, it has to do with how local variables come one after the other in memory.  So when `printf` goes beyond your array boundary into la-la land, it ends up printing another variable in memory.  But this is outside the scope of C.  The language C just says the behavior is undefined if you go off into la-la land.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C standard, the *printf* function prints the character in the string until it finds a null character. Otherwise, after the defined array index, what it will do is not defined.

I have tested your code. And after printing "`abcdefghij`", it prints some garbage value.

Comment: I am using codeblocks IDE and I do not get any garbage value . Which compiler are you using . Should I consider changing my compiler ? thanks .

Comment: **Your code is invalid.  Your code's behavior is undefined.**  The C spec said that reading beyond the end of the array is undefined behavior, meaning that the compiler can make anything happen.  The compiler is not broken.  Your code is.

Answer (score 1):

If you do other things before that call, your stack area will contain other data than an unused one. Imagine that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int use_stack(void) {
   char str[500];
   memset(str, 'X', sizeof(str));
   printf("Filled memory from %p to %p.\n", &str, &str + sizeof str);
}

void print_stuff() {
    int i;
    char str[16]; // Changed that so that 10..15 contain X
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        str[i] = (char)(i+97);
    }

    printf("%s<END>", str); // Have a line break before <END>? Then it comes from i.
    printf("&str: %p\n", &str);
    printf("&i: %p\n", &i);
    // Here you see that i follows str as &i is &str + 16 (0x10 in hex)
}

int main() {
    use_stack();
    print_stuff();
}
```

your stack area will be full of `X`es, and `printf()` will see them.

In your situation and your environment, the stack is coincidentally "clean" on program start.

This may or may not happen. If the compiler puts the variable `i` immediately after the array, your data will nevertheless be `NUL`-terminated, because the first byte is the value of `i` (which you happen to print as well—it might be a libne break in your case—and the second byte is a `NUL` byte. Even if this is the case, your code invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (undefined behaviour).

Can you have a look (by piping the program output into [`hexdump`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump) or alike) if your output contains a `0A` character? If so, my guess is correct. I just tested it, and on my compiler (GCC) it seems to be the way.

As said, nothing you should rely on.
If you see a line break before `<END>`, my guess was right. And if you have a look at the pointers now being printed, you can compare their addresses in memory.

Comment: I don't know what a hexdump is but the code you gave runs without crashing or printing any garbage values . I am running the code on code blocks IDE on windows 7 .

Comment: @NikunjBanka Yeah, it was because of the said fact that `i` follows `str` on the stack and because `str[]` is fully used. If you do `str[15]`, the elements 10..14 of `str[]` will be filled with `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Because in debug mode, `*(str+10)` and the whole unused space have an initialized value '0', so it seems like it's 0 terminated.

```
clang -O0 t.c -o t # Compile in debug mode
./t
```

Output:

```
abcdefghij
```

And:

```
clang -O2 t.c -o t # Compile with optimization
./t
```

Output:

```
abcdefghij2÷d=
```

Comment: But the `NUL` character is expected to sit behind the array. So it doesn't matter if `str[]` is initialized to `\0` (where do you think that happens?), the oddity lies beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: I mean `*(str+10)`, not the whole array in the bounds.