# Printing a string in C

Tags: c, string

I understand that in C, a string is an array of characters with a special `'\0'` character at the end of the array.

Say I have "Hello" stored in a `char*` named string and there is a `'\0'` at the end of the array.

When I call `printf("%s\n", string);`, it would print out "Hello".

My question is, what happens to `'\0'` when you call `printf` on a string?

Comment: Nothing. it's just an indicator so printf knows when to stop printing chars.

Comment: what if '\0' is not included in the array and you call printf on it?

Comment: then you have a bug :)

Comment: @drumGod31 It will keep printing until it encounters a '\0' or until you get a segfault.

Comment: "what if '\0' is not included in the array"  --> tell when to stop `printf("%.*s\n", max_characters_to_printf, array_without_null_chracter)`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656377/how-come-printf-is-printing-a-non-null-terminated-string?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @drumGod: The `%s` conversion specifier basically means, "print the sequence of characters starting at the specified location until you encounter a string terminator"; if there's no string terminator in the array you passed, then `printf` will keep printing characters from the memory past that array until it sees the terminator.

Answer (score 2):

The null character (`'\0'`) at the end of a string is simply a sentinel value for C library functions to know where to stop processing a string pointer.

This is necessary for two reasons:

1. Arrays decay to pointers to their first element when passed to functions
2. It's entirely possible to have a string in an array of `char`s that doesn't use up the entire array.

For example, `strlen`, which determines the length of the string, might be implemented as:

```
size_t strlen(char *s)
{
     size_t len = 0;
     while(*s++ != '\0') len++;
     return len;
}
```

If you tried to emulate this behavior inline with a statically allocated array instead of a pointer, you still need the null terminator to know the string length:

```
char str[100];
size_t len = 0;

strcpy(str, "Hello World");
    
for(; len < 100; len++)    
    if(str[len]=='\0') break;

// len now contains the string length
```

Note that explicitly comparing for inequality with `'\0'` is redundant; I just included it for ease of understanding.

Comment: Or even lazier: `while (*s++)`