# Correct way to printf() a std::string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17, printf, string-view

I am new to C++17 and to `std::string_view`.
I learned that they are not null terminated and must be handled with care.

Is this the right way to printf() one?

```
#include<string_view>
#include<cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::string_view sv{"Hallo!"};
    printf("=%*s=\n", static_cast<int>(sv.length()), sv.data());
    return 0;
}
```

(or use it with any other printf-style function?)

Comment: Why you want to use `printf` in c++ at all?

Comment: *I learned that they are not null terminated* That's not entirely correct.  A `string_view` can be non-null terminated, but only if you create it as such.  `"Hallo"` has a null terminator, so `sv` will as well.

Comment: Is this what you are asking?  [Using printf with a non-null terminated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767284/using-printf-with-a-non-null-terminated-string)

Comment: I believe it should be `"=%.*s=\n"`... Just checked, that's correct.

Comment: @DrewDormann No, but this is clearly answerering the same question. Did not think about searching for this...

Comment: I don't get the downvote, although using `char str[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}; std::string_view sv(str, 5);` in the question would have been better. Got my upvote anyway.

Comment: @MarekR  I change existing code, which excessively uses printf(). I want to keep the style and not change to much of it. My code above is obviously just a shortended example.

Comment: Consider use `fmt` library it should easy to transform code which uses `printf`.

Comment: @kuga Did you manage to get it to work? You said that both answers are  _"clearly wrong"_ but they are both correct.  See [`std::printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes `%.*s` works. I meant: Without the dot, its clearly wrong.

Comment: @kuga Oh, then I misunderstood you and thought that since you didn't accept any answer, you didn't think they were correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is strange requirement, but it is possible:

```cpp
std::string_view s{"Hallo this is longer then needed!"};
auto sub = s.substr(0, 5);
printf("=%.*s=\n", static_cast<int>(sub.length()), sub.data());
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nbeMWo1G1

As you can see you were close to solution.

Comment: casting to an `int` can lead to UB.  Does `printf` support passing a `size_t` for the length of the string?

Comment: @NathanOliver No, only `int` is supported.

Comment: @eeroroka has the same answer, but I just say it here: The dot (`.`) is the __precision__, without its the __minimum field__ length which is clearly wrong.

Comment: btw: The requirement is to not change the existing code, which excessively uses printf(), to much and keep the style ;)

Comment: @kuga No, it's not wrong. The `*` is what receives the precision. So, `'.5s', sv.data()` or `'.*s', (int)sv.size(), sv.data()` does the same thing (as long as `size()` doesn't overflow the `int`).

Comment: `printf` requires `int` value there so cast is needed. `Star` parameter doesn't have any modifiers to change expected type. It is possible to implement safe casting to `int`, but IMO it would be overkill.

Comment: I was more thinking to implement template which could be called `clip_cast`.

Comment: @MarekR `clip_cast` got a nice ring to it!

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
assert(sv.length() <= INT_MAX);
std::printf(
    "%.*s",
    static_cast<int>(sv.length()),
    sv.data());
```

Answer (score -4):

The thing to remember about `string_view` is that it will never modify the underlying character array. So, if you pass a C-string to the `string_view` constructor, the `sv.data()` method will always return *the same* C-string.

So, this specific case will always work:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::string_view sv {"Hallo!"};
    printf("%s\n", sv.data());
}
```

Comment: I'd warn against doing this in the general case, since not all views are null-terminated.

Comment: @holyBlackCat – i was very specific that it's only for C-string constructed `string_view` objects.

Comment: not sure why this is "-2" since in the above requested case the string_view is null-term. see ctor #4 in string_view in cppref. Yes, it's a view that is not null term, but I'd change the original question to be more general.

Comment: Access to basic_string_view::operator[](size()) (the nul terminator in this case) has undefined behaviour. You can use this trick because it works, but you should feel dirty every time, I do :-(