# How can std::string_view be constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, string-view

I tried to find the answer on SO but failed. Sorry if this is a duplicate. I will close the question then.

Could you explain the difference between:

```
constexpr const char Str1[] = "qwerty";
constexpr auto Str1Size = sizeof(Str1) - 1;
```

and

```
constexpr std::string_view Str2{"qwerty"};
constexpr auto Str2Size = Str2.size();
```

I saw the second variant today and failed to understand. AFAIU `std::string_view` is a dynamic object, so memory will be dynamically allocated. So how can be this `constexpr`?

Also, if these variants are really both okay, i.e. are compile-time, then what is their difference? AFAIK, `Str2` will not have `'\0'` and the end of it. Is it all?

Comment: `std::string_view` does not allocate any memory. It's only a view, it stores a pointer and number of characters.

Comment: `std::string_view` is just fancy form of const reference to a string. In case of `costexpr` it is const reference to a string literal.

Comment: "std::string_view is a dynamic object, so memory will be dynamically allocated", No, its not. `std::string` will alocate memory, but `std::string_view ` will only hold pointer to the external data

Comment: So except for the lack of `'\0' and the end`, there is no difference?

Comment: It only lacks `\0` if the string it points to lacks it. `std::string_view` is effectively just a struct with a `const char *ptr; std::size_t size;` in it.

Comment: There is no warranty that std::string_view is null terminated. See example where this is a problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/72575650/1387438

Comment: So in my example, is it possible to say if `Str2` is null-terminated or not?

Comment: @JenyaKh obviosly, it is. `"qwerty"` Is array of 7 `const char`s, not 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AFAIU `std::string_view` is a dynamic object, so memory will be dynamically allocated. So how can be this `constexpr`?

`std::string_view` is *not* dynamically allocated. It is essentially a `const char*` to the character data and the string length, combined into one object. This can obviously be `constexpr`. You might be thinking of `std::string`, which is dynamically allocated.

Note that

```cpp
constexpr const char* str = "qwerty";
```

... is valid, since `"qwerty"` is not dynamically allocated but has static storage duration. `str` points to this string literal. If you wrap this in a `std::string_view`, the `str` pointer gets copied. None of this involves dynamic allocation.

> Also, if these variants are really both okay, i.e. are compile-time, then what is their difference? AFAIK, `Str2` will not have `'\0'` and the end of it. Is it all?

The null terminator is the only significant difference. `std::string_view` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, so you lose safe access<sup>(1)</sup> to it when wrapping the character data in a `std::string_view`. `std::string_view` is also a standard library container, and has an interface which is much nicer to work with. You can create substrings with `.substr`, etc.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>Specifically, the null terminator is still contained in the string data, which can be accessed with `.data()`. However, an arbitrary `std::string_view` may not be null-terminated, making it unsafe and bug-prone to rely on it being null-terminated. There is also no safe way to check whether a `std::string_view` is null-terminated at run-time, so either you (blindly) believe it, or you assume that it isn't.</sub>

Comment: But you already have `size` as the number of reliable characters. So in case you need to interface C API, you can use the `n` infixed versions(` `strndup` instead of `strdup`...). All that null served was to mark the end of string, now you get it with `size`. Unless size is explicitly fed to ctor, or  array(or `std::array`, `std::vector`) is used as initializer, the null character is still at the tail. By wrapping/boxing `string_view`, you can constrain it to either category of null or none-null terminated strings.