Is replacing all const std::string & with std::string_view a good choice?
I am very sensitive about memory allocation and copy. So, if a function needs a std::string object as input, I always use const std::string &.
Recently, I found const std::string & will contruct a std::string object if I pass in a char[]:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
         
using namespace std;
         
void test_string(const std::string & s) {  // use std::string_view here is better
  // it can avoid local variable allocation
  printf("%p\n", s.data());
}        
         
int main() {
  char aa[] = "asd";
  test_string(aa);
  printf("%p\n", aa);
}

I changed the const std::string & to std::string_view, and it solved the unnecessary construction or copy. So, I think std::string_view is worthy to be used everywhere.
I replaced all const std::string & with std::string_view, if there is some place I need to use std::string, I use .data() to get the string.
Problems happen in the following sitution:
inline std::vector<std::string_view> Split(std::string_view str, std::string_view delim, const bool trim_empty = false) {
    if (str.empty()) return {}; 
    size_t pos, last_pos = 0, len;
    std::vector<std::string_view> tokens;
    while (true) {
      pos = str.find(delim, last_pos);
      if (pos == std::string::npos) pos = str.size();
      len = pos - last_pos;
      if (!trim_empty || len != 0) tokens.push_back(str.substr(last_pos, len));
      if (pos == str.size()) break; 
      else last_pos = pos + delim.size();
    }   
    return tokens;
  }

I use this to split a string into a vector, as you can see, the std::string_view avoids a copy and big memory allocation.
But the problem happens in using the std::string_view:
std::string str = "asd\nbn\ncd\n\n";
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;
m["asd"] = 2;
const auto & v = Split(str, "\n");
const auto & it = m.find(v.front().data());

This failed because v.front().data() returns the whole string, not the first part.
I know this is caused by no "\0" in the string stream.
It seems there is no good way to find the correct std::string_view, except for constructing a std::string using std::string(v.front().data()).
So, is there any way I can make .data() end as expected? Or is replacing const std::string & with std::string_view just not always a good choice?

"if there is some place need to use std::string, I use .data() to get the string." I do not understand. If you need a std::string you need to use a std::string not something else.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72575650/1387438

"I am very sensitive about memory allocation and copy..." I don't think this needs to be in the post/question

This specific issue would still be happening if you had const std::string& instead. If you had std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string& str, const std::string& delim, const bool trim_empty = false) before, it should have become std::vector<std::string> Split(std::string_view str, std::string_view delim, const bool trim_empty = false);, since the vector doesn't have a const std::string&. Also in C++20 you can use a transparent unordered_map.

If your function needs the string to be std::string somewhere, passing as std::string_view will be more wasteful.  If your function needs the string to be a null-terminated const char * somewhere, passing as std::string_view will be broken.

Your question's title does not match its body. The title looks like a duplicate of When would I pass const& std::string instead of std::string_view?, but your question appears to be more about using a std::string_view to find an entry in a std::unordered_map whose keys are std::string, preferably without constructing a string.

std::string_view::data() returns a pointer that is not necessarily null-terminated.
std::string::data() returns a pointer that is always null-terminated (since C++11).
std::string constructor 9 that accepts char* requires it to point to a null-terminated string.
Since you construct temporary std::string anyway, do it properly: std::string{v.front()} will construct string of correct length from std::string_view.
Or, if this is the only use of Split, don't use std::string_view at all, there doesn't seem to be a lot of gain if you use string_view only to construct string out of it.

Also, outside of the question, but as Botje noticed in comment, your usage of references is wrong. The objects they refer to both die at ; ending respective line and you are left with dangling references.

The main problem here is that you are constructing a string from a string_view for the sole purpose of using it with map.find, in which case you probably want to call the constructor of string that accepts a string_view instead of passing a char* so it doesn't need to call strlen. (do std::string{the_string_view} explicitly) but that's not the real solution to the problem.
Normally std::unordered_map has find and the comparator and the hasher only accept the key type as argument, so find fails for string_view if Key is std::string, you will have to define your own hasher and comparator, and you will need C++20 for the overload that accepts any type that is comparable to the key for find
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

struct Equality
{
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    bool operator()(const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) const { 
        auto result = lhs == rhs;
        return result;
    }
};
struct Hash
{
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    template <typename T>
    size_t operator()(const T& obj) const { 
        auto result = std::hash<std::decay_t<T>>{}(obj);
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int, Hash, Equality> m{ {"hel",1} };
    std::string s = "hello";
    std::string_view sv{ s };
    sv = sv.substr(0, 3);
    auto it = m.find(sv);
    if (it != m.end())
    {
        std::cout << "found!";
    }
}

Note that you need a C++20 compiler to run this code, otherwise you will have to use Boost's version of the container which already has this overload for lower c++ versions, or any another implementation that has this overload.

One last option if you are stuck on c++17 and unable to migrate to C++20 or use boost or any other library is to make your own container that stores std::string in a set and a corresponding std::string_view in the map keys, so that you can use string_view as an argument to find ... but this is wasteful for memory (extra 16 bytes per key)
