# Printing 2 strings causes an unexpected result

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to print two different strings, but when printing it combines both of them and then prints the other by itself. Can someone explain?

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(){
  char SPU4[3]= "N/A";
  char EU4[]= "ok";
  printf ("%s\n", SPU4);
  printf ("%s\n", EU4);  
}
```

It ends up printing:

```
N/Aok
ok
```

When I want it to print:

```
N/A
ok
```

Comment: `printf()` expects null-terminated strings for `%s`. You're not providing them.

Comment: `SPU4` should be at least 4 `char`s long to accomodate the null termination. Check your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

`"N/A"` is a [**null-teminated string**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) literal. It means it requires 4 `char`s (1 additional `char` for the null-termination).
In this line:

```
char SPU4[3]= "N/A";
```

You define `SPU4` to have only 3 `char`s, which means `SPU4` will not contain the null-termination.

On the other hand `printf` with `%s` expects a null-terminated string and as explained above `SPU4` is not one. This is causing [undefined-behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The fix is simply to replace the line above with:

```
char SPU4[] = "N/A";
```

Which is the approach you already took corectly with `EU4`.
By not specifying the array length you tell the compiler to determine the correct one according to the string literal you assign to it.

If for some reason you must have `SPU4` to be only 3 `char`s long, you can use `printf` with `"%.*s"` and supply the length in the following way:

```
printf ("%.*s\n", (int)sizeof SPU4, SPU4);
```

See this post for more info: [Using printf with a non-null terminated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767284/using-printf-with-a-non-null-terminated-string).

Comment: Actually, no. In C, `char SPU4[3] = "N/A";` is defined behaviour; it initializes the byte array with 3 characters and there is no null terminator (so it is not a string). See C11 [§6.7.9 Initialization ¶14](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14): _An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array._ C++ has different, saner rules.

Comment: @wohlstad Are you sure that you have a buffer overflow and UB?  I think it's legal to initialize an array with a string literal omitting the NUL terminator in C.  `char SPU4[3] = "ABCDEFG";` gives `initializer-string for char array is too long` but `char SPU4[3] = "ABC";` does not even warn.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Wyck - My mistake (I believe it not legal in C++ which got me confused). Corrected my answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Wyck BTW I think there's still UB here calling `printf` with `%s` (for `SPU4`). Am I wrong ?

Comment: You are correct that printing `SPU4` with `%s` leads to UB.

Comment: @wohlstad, Or `printf ("%.*s\n", 3, SPU4);` --> `printf ("%.*s\n", (int)sizeof SPU4, SPU4);` which avoids hard coding the `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the size of SPU4 from 3 to 4 so that it includes null terminator at last which makes it as string .

Comment: I think it is better to let the compiler determine the correct length. See my answer.